# After Interview Reply

Tags: american-english, british-english, business-language

I was interviewed 3 days ago which went well and It was my last interview with respective department Head for the position. I didn't receive any reply after the interview so I contacted the HR guy through email and asked about the status of my application. He responded "I didn’t go through. I wish you best luck for future."

I am a bit confused now as I don't get it If he mistakenly wrote "I" instead of "you" to inform me I am rejected or he wants to say he didn't go through and he is waiting for a response from Head of the department?

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: It's a typo for "I**t** [your application] didn't go through".  The final phrase "I wish you luck in the future" tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: Probably just a typo, the missing letter is "t", it (the application) didn't go through.